# printer is detected as other devices instead of a printer

Tags: windows-10, printer

I have windows 10 build 1607 and I'm trying to make my printer work under it.

My printer model is hp laserjet 1300 series and its driver is installed, I can see it in device manager under two categories: one under USB as Dot4USB and other as IEEE printer.

But under "Devices and Printers" it's still detected as other devices, I tried all sort of things without luck.

When I click "Add a printer" windows doesn't detect it, when I reach the dialog where I select a printer from a list of models I can't see my model in there and I don't have its CD.

I tried plugging it into different USB ports without success.

So what should I do ?

Comment: Exactly which driver did you use?  Was it a [Windows 10 specific driver from HP](https://support.hp.com/za-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-1300-printer-series/238320)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 no, it was the driver from windows update

Answer (score 1):

Completely delete Dot4USB and IEEE printer from Device Manager, then install HP LaserJet USB (DOT4) communication driver and HP Printer Administrator Resource Kit from official website.

HP LaserJet 1300 Printer series

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-1300-printer-series/238320

Make sure your Windows is up to date.

Comment: I installed DOT4 but I can't tell how to use HP printer administrator resource kit because there are so many programs and I can't identify the driver from them

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but the files mentioned in the previous answer (Dot4USB and IEEE printer) were not even present on my machine.  However when I downloaded the software from https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-1300-printer-series/238320 (under "Driver-USB") and ran it, the LaserJet printer was identified under "Printers & scanners" and disappeared from "Bluetooth & other devices".  It then worked!